# How to merge two json arrays in Python

Tags: python, arrays, json, merge

I am looping through a WebService in Python which returns me partially data. I am calling the WebService until i receive an "End of Data" in the response.

The returned objects are always the same structure. They are only part of a large data which the WebService returns in chunks of 1000.

I am saving the returned JSON string in a `data` variable. How can i copy JSON array `data_next` to JSON array in variable `data' or merge both JSON files.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to merge two dictionaries in a single expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38987/how-to-merge-two-dictionaries-in-a-single-expression)

Comment: You should post an example of the data you are receiving.

Comment: The answer will depend on the format of the data you're receiving. Send an example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let say you receive something like `resp1 = '{"data": [...]}'` and store it in a dictionary `d`. Assuming you do that using json package as follows:

```
d = json.loads(resp1)
```

For the next batch of data, you should store it in a temporal dictionary `td`, extract the field "data_next" and append it into the original dictionary:

```
td = json.loads(respN)
d["data"].append(td["data_next"])
```

Comment: I will try it and give feedback. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Let us consider two list A =[{"a":"apple"},{"b":"banana"}]
and list B = [{"c":"cat"}]

try below in python 3 to get merged array.

```
A.__add__(B)
```

Comment: isn't this the same as `A += B`?